# retrieve record from mongodb in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Created some mobiles and stored in mongodb. For each user separate mobiles are created and stored in Database .Now i want to retrieve all the mobiles from database

I have 2 models : Mobile Model and a User Model

thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

As not providing any details about the mongodb gem used, I can only answer:

```
Use the Mobile Model :->
```

**Edit 1:**
It was a bit sarcastic answer. But it is true. If you are using mognoid for example, and have something like this:

```
class Mobile
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

You can then call:

```
 Mobile.all
 #or even

 Mobile.each {|mobile| process(mobile)  }
```